# Hibernate Many to Many mapping, update same child in multiple parents

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I have created two entities, Project and Employee. One Project can have multiple employees, multiple Projects can have multiple employees, So I have chosen ManytoMany relationship, correct me if it is wrong. Since I have to retrieve all the projects in which employee i working and all the employees which are part of one project. 
Sample entity classes are below.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "projects")
public class Project {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "project_employee", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "project_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id"))
    private Set<Employee> employee;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "employee")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Set<Project> project = new HashSet<Project>();

    private String status;
}
```

Let us say there are 2 projects with id 1 & 2 
4 employees with id 1,2,3,4.

employee 1,2,3 are part of first project
employee 2,3,4 are part of second project.

employee 2 completed the first project so employee entity status should be completed for first project
employee 2 blocked in second project so employee entity status should be blocked for 2nd project

So the problem I am facing is if I update employee 2 status for first project , same will appear for second project as well vice versa also true.

So how to tackle this, do I need create separate entity for status by add both employee and project mapping.

Comment: Yes, project id, employee id and status

Comment: Thanks. How new entity will look like. And is there any better approach in designing the employee and project entites

Comment: in my opinion there's a better way to do this, make project_employee a new entity and add status column there

Comment: That I got it, but how to connect employee and project to project_employee.

Comment: I guess by creating list of project_employee in project and employee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The employee 2, who works in the first and second project, is always the same entry.
When you update the employee status, it will be updated for both projects, because both projects use the same entry.

If you want to persist, that employee 2 completed his work for project 1, but is still working on project 2, you need a separate table, which saves the information about status, employee id and project id

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "projects")
public class Project {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "project_employee", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "project_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id"))
    private Set<Employee> employee;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "employee")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Set<Project> project = new HashSet<Project>();

    @OneToMany
    private Set<Status> status = new HashSet<Status>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "status")
public class Status {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id
    private String status; // completed, in progress, ... (think about making an enum)
    @ManyToOne
    private Employee employee;
    @ManyToOne
    private Project project;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. How new entity will look like.

Comment: @vighneshwar i didn't try it out, but it should look like this

Comment: Sure I will check. Thank you.

Comment: @vighneshwar did it work? If yes, please accept the answer